# S3 Policy : Authorize full access for some users and resrouces but Read Only for VPC Endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket and want to give these permissions :

All users throught the AWS console can have full access (read, list, write), also some other resources Like EMR Cluster, EC2 instances.

At the same time, any connection from a list of a VPC endpoints should have only Read and List access

I tried that but it denied also the access from console.

```
{
"Effect": "Deny",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": [
    "s3:Get*",
    "s3:List*"
],
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3::: MY_BUCKET",
    "arn:aws:s3::: MY_BUCKET/*"
],
"Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {"aws:SourceVpce": [
        "vpce-ID1",
        "vpce-ID2"
    ]}
}
}
```

Comment: your condition needs to be `StringEquals`

Comment: No that way it will block the VPCE, i want the opposite of that